# How to figure out which cat6 config is being used?

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, cat6

In true builder fashion I am left to terminate the cat 6 cables wired throughout my new house. I opened the cat6 wall plug to see what order they used so I can match it in the basement...and I have no idea what I'm looking at. It's in a little box thing. Please see pictures.[image: picOne]
[image: picTwo]

I was watching a YouTube video on how to terminate the other end, and the guy in the video said to make sure the order is the same. I'm unsure of what order this is.

Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: There are guides online for doing this. You can follow the instructions that came with the plates, or you can look for guides online. What have you done?

Comment: It's sealed off I can't see what is connected where. The builder installed these so there aren't any instructions that they left behind.

Comment: *"I opened the cat6 wall plug ..."* -- A wall plate would have a RJ45 socket, not a plug.

Comment: If you cannot visually determine the wiring scheme, then a cable tester, or a standard multimeter (e.g. DMM) on the continuity setting with a (long) external cable to "loopback" to one end of the in-wall cable, can electrically determine the connections.

Comment: You could also simply ignore the existing connection, and start over with new connectors on both ends of the cable with the wiring scheme of your choice.  What you pictured is not ideal: too much length of the twisted pairs appear to have been separated.

Comment: That's a good idea. I might just do that, redo the connectors and replace the rj45 socket. Just sucks the builder did such a lousy job after charging me so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images on the side show both the T568A and the T568B wiring as described e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable).

Usually one of these is used, and you have to decide which one.

Unfortunately you do not show the part of the box where the cables go in, I'd assume there are little numbers next to the hole, so you can check which cable goes in where.

If you are unlucky, the part on the right side is an extra covering, that you'll need to remove before you'll see the numbers. Then you either have to carefully figure out how to "unlock" the plastic latches that are probably somewhere in there, so you can actually remove it and have a look, or you'll have to use a multimeter or LAN cable tester.

Since you are doing your own wiring, and can recommend a cable tester - it will save you much time during trouble shooting.

Cat6 cables come in two variants, solid core and stranded core. Usually solid core is used for the longer connection inside walls, and you'll need a special tool to clamp the solid core wires to the Cat6 wall plug, anyway. Without this tool it's next to impossible to make a good connection (which will degrade your speed, and then we'll have a "why doesn't my Cat6 deliver the full speed" question).

So buy the right tool for the plugs you want to use together with a cable tester, they often come combined.

(And though you said you want to use wall plugs, so it doesn't apply: don't try to crimp connectors intended for stranded-core wires to solid-core wires. That's a popular newbie mistake, and it's not going to work.)

---

> The other side of the box has wires going in but no numbering

While I'd still like to see a picture of this, then I'd assume that the numbering on the sides is relevant. So matching the colors I can see in the first picture, you have

2 = green, 1 = white, 6 = orange, 3 = white, ...

which means it's the A variant.

So wire the other side also using the A variant.

(But still go buy a cable tester, you are going to need it).

Comment: Sorry I called the rj45 sockets in the wall plate a plug. That wall plate I pulled out the line runs down to the basement where I need to put the cat6 wires into a rj45 jack and crimp then I can insert to a network switch which will be connected to my router. The other side of the box has wires going in but no numbering just on the sides shown in the picture that's why I'm confused. But! I like your suggestion will try! Thanks

Comment: I was able to see the wires on the side and match it up with the numbers. Thanks for pointing that out with the standards. Took a long time but finally figured out which one goes where, thank the engineers for label makers lol thanks again dirkt!